# Org agenda - alias for file name in weekly view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Some of the org files I use have long filenames (at least longer than 11 characters ;)), this breaks the default weekly view:

[image: broken weekly agenda example]

`elastic-oncall` is longer than the space for filename and therefore breaks the format.

Is there a way to specify file name alias, or just make it truncate the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string that appears in the agenda is, in general, the category to which the entry belongs. But the file name is used as a fallback.

You could then add a category to your whole `elastic-oncall` with, eg.:

```
#+CATEGORY: el-onc
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @gusbrs ! BTW category can be also specified for a subtree, which is great https://orgmode.org/manual/Categories.html